# Obtain text file with temperature values

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

By the end of it, I am supposed to have a .txt file with a temperature value for every day of 2009. The problem is, the file this code creates is only giving me 12 values (one for each month) and half of them are from dates that aren't real (i.e. April 31).

I'm not fluent in Python, but I've reviewed my textbook and the code several times and can find no discrepancies.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#CSV
f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')

#months, days
for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in range(1, 32):

     #get if already gone through month
     if (m == 2 and d > 28):
       break
     elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
       break

     #open wunderground.com url
     timestamp = '2009' + str(m) + str(d)
     print "Getting data for " + timestamp
     url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2009/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
     page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    #get temp from page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    #dayTemp = soup.body.nobr.b.string
    dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"nobr"})[4].span.string

    #Format month for timestamp
    if len(str(m)) < 2:
     mStamp = '0' + str(m)
    else:
     mStamp = str(m)

    #Format day for timestamp
    if len(str(d)) < 2:
     dStamp = '0' + str(d)
    else:
     dStamp = str(d)

    #Build timestamp
    timestamp = '2009' + mStamp + dStamp

    #Write timestamp and temperature to file
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')

# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi! could you please be more specific in what you're asking? You should add details as to what input data you used, what results you expect, and what results you have observed. Plus, please add information on what you have already tried to solve the problems you faced yourself. _Please review my codebase_ usually is not a legitimate question, on this site. You should cut out everything that is not useful in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems that most of your problem stems from *reinventing the wheel* concerning date manipulation and date string generation. Please have a look at [the documentation of `datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime).

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())` is the first error i think. You forget read() function

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with indentation of your code. Part of code from `#get if already..` till `page = urllib2.urlopen(url)` is indented more, so it is only part of inner loop. Parsing the webpage content and writing to file is within outer loop. It is why you grab just last day of months (in fact mostly invalid as your loop is defined till 31 for each month).

You can use `datetime` to iterate days of year correctly, i.e:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while d < end_date:
    print "Getting data for " + d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2009/%d/%d/DailyHistory.html" % (d.day, d.month)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    #process web content and write to file

    d += delta

# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```